# Why is the size of the human penis not in proportion to that of the rest of the body?

Tags: genetics

According to this research

https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-2ffcc3b19663af67c96ac1be8f3d6351-c

it is more likely for tall men to have large penis

but there are still many tall not having large

It is clearly not matching the size of other organs such as arms, legs, hearts, etc.

If you see a tall man you can see he has long arms, long thighs, bigger heart, etc.

similarly for short men, they have short arms , legs ,etc.

why it is not the same for penis?

why tall men may have short penis or short men may have long ones?

why the length of the penis does not match with make height similar to other organs?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It is expected that you will demonstrate that you have done research on your own before asking questions here — at a minimum please supply a credible source showing that human penises deviate more from their expected proportions than other parts of the human body. ——— Please also take the time to check out the [tour] and then the help pages starting with [Ask] questions on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Asymmetric is the wrong word. That would mean that one half (along the length) does not appear to be the mirror image of the other. "Male" would appear to be redundant also. You should edit your question say something like "Why is the size of the human penis not in proportion to that of the rest of the body?" (Remember the question mark.)

Comment: Why are some people more intelligent than others? Why are some people taller than others? Perhaps all theses have the same or similar answer...

Comment: @SolarMike it is definately not the same. the intelligence is not a physical thing, it is not an organ. taller people have tall arms, tall legs etc. there is a percentage of proportion that goes with these organs ( like your heart size is matching your fest size) to a certain degree is accurate. but for penis there is no theory that works, foot size is false, and penis size vary for the same tall people ( so my question again why penis size vary (biologically what causing this difference in size, why it is not same as other organs matching a percentage of the human tall))

Answer (score -1):

According to genetics all phenotypical characters are inherited from both biological parents. The Y chromosome is mainly responsible for appearance of male characters and the only source of getting Y chromosome is from biological father. However other traits i.e. of height  can be inherited from either biological father or mother. Therefore if the height of mother was taller and is dominant over father's height then the child will be having the mother's height. The Y chromosome related characters would remain same and you would not observe any change in male character.  Therefore, you can not relate all physical characters with Y-chromosomal characters.

Comment: but you don't see a tall man (coz the father was tall) with short arms (coz mother was short and has short arms) all organs for tall men are tall and big that matches that tall. except for penis it is vary for the same tall people

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Your answer over simplifies the genetics of both penis size and height (for evidence start here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_penis_size). Inclusion of references is also highly desirable. ——— Please take the [tour] and then consult the help pages on the standards for [answer] effectively. Thanks! 